# python TypeError "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" Why am I getting this?

Tags: python

When I run this code I, it will ask me What move do you want to choose: just as it's meant to. But if I enter rock and anything else it will say

> ```
> popularity = str(int(open("/Users/timothy/Documents/" + move[playermove + ".txt",r]).read()) + 1)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.
> ```

I have checked that everything is string so why is this the case?

My code:

```
while True:
    move = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    movenumber = 0
    computermove = ChooseMove()
    go = 1
    while go == 1:
        playermove = move.index(input("What move do you want to choose:   "))
        popularity = str(int(open("/Users/timothy/Documents/" + move[playermove + ".txt",r]).read()) + 1)
        (open("/Users/timothy/Documents/" + move[playermove] + ".txt","w")).write(popularity)
        go = 2
    print ()
    print ("The computer picked " + move[computermove])
    print ()
    if playermove - computermove == 1:
        print ("Player won")
    elif playermove - computermove == 2:
        print ("Player lost")
    elif playermove - computermove == -1:
        print ("Player lost")
    elif playermove - computermove == -2:
        print ("Player won")
    else:
        print ("It's a draw")
```

Comment: 1 is not a sring.

Comment: By the way, you can use `(movea - moveb) % 3` to get 0, 1 or 2 without negatives, so you won't need to check twice for each win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an error in writing

```
move[playermove + ".txt",r])
```

It should be where you should also replace `r` by `'r'`

```
move[playermove] + ".txt",'r')
```

Comment: I did realise that before and in the actual code wrote it like move[playermove] yet it still thinks it is move[playermove without the closing bracket. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Did you also replace `r` by `'r'`?

Comment: I had not originally but now have. However it still displays the error

Comment: What do you get when you do `print (open("/Users/timothy/Documents/" + move[playermove] + ".txt",'r').read())`